# Inserting function in order to get search results for movie titles

Tags: javascript, api

I am trying to get my search box to produce movie results after clicking submit button. Where do I insert this function in order to get it working?

```
  function getSearchResult() {
  var search = document.getElementById("title").innerHTML;
  jQuery.getJSON(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${apiKey}&i=${movieID}` + search + "=json", function(result) {
    jQuery.each(result, function(i, field) {
      jQuery("div").append(field + " ");
    });
```

Here is the block of code that I am trying to insert this function in:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let button = document.getElementById("button");
    var apiKey = "72926e20";
    $.get(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${apiKey}&s=wolf`, function (
        data
    ) {
        console.log(data);
        for (let i = 0; i < data.Search.length; i++) {
            let titleList = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
            let listLi = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[0];
            let li = document.createElement("li")
            let title = document.createElement("div");
            let titleBody = document.createElement(   "div");
            let poster = document.createElement("img");
            let yearRelease = document.createElement("div");
            let button = document.createElement("button");
            //This gives the poster the image
            poster.src = `${data.Search[i].Poster}`;
            ///This will return the API data
            titleBody.innerHTML = data.Search[i].Title;
            yearRelease.innerHTML = data.Search[i].Year;
            button.innerHTML = "get movie info";
            
            poster.className = "card-img-top";
            yearRelease.className = "card-body"
            titleBody.className = "card-title"
           
           title.appendChild(poster);
           title.appendChild(titleBody);
           title.appendChild(yearRelease)
           title.appendChild(button);
           li.appendChild(title);
           button.addEventListener('click',() => {
                $.get(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${apiKey}&i=${movieID}`, function (data) {
                    console.log(title)
                });
                // title.src = data.Search[i].Title
                console.log(title)
            }
            );
           listLi.appendChild(li);
          
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the changes below, it will help you to get going:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getSearchResult() {
            var movieID = this.value
            jQuery.getJSON(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${apiKey}&i=${movieID}`, function (result) {
                jQuery.each(result, function (i, field) {
                    jQuery("#" + movieID).append(field + " ");
                });
            });
        }

        let button = document.getElementById("button");
        var apiKey = "72926e20";
        $.get(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${apiKey}&s=wolf`, function (
            data
        ) {
            console.log(data);
            for (let i = 0; i < data.Search.length; i++) {
                let titleList = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
                let listLi = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[0];
                let li = document.createElement("li")
                let title = document.createElement("div");
                let titleBody = document.createElement("div");
                let poster = document.createElement("img");
                let yearRelease = document.createElement("div");
                let button = document.createElement("button");
                //This gives the poster the image
                poster.src = `${data.Search[i].Poster}`;
                ///This will return the API data
                titleBody.innerHTML = data.Search[i].Title;
                yearRelease.innerHTML = data.Search[i].Year;
                button.innerHTML = "get movie info";

                poster.className = "card-img-top";
                yearRelease.className = "card-body"
                titleBody.className = "card-title"

                title.appendChild(poster);
                title.appendChild(titleBody);
                title.appendChild(yearRelease)
                title.appendChild(button);
                let movieID = data.Search[i].imdbID;
                $('<div>', {id: movieID}).appendTo(title);
                li.appendChild(title);
                button.value = movieID;
                button.addEventListener('click', getSearchResult);
                listLi.appendChild(li);
            }
        });
    </script>
```